# spring core aws messaging Notification template not binding the message properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am using spring-boot-2.2.1 along with AWS SNS & SQS. I was publishing a message from SNS to SQS. I am able to receive the message using String but @NotificationMessage is returning null instead of the message body. The same code was working fine when I was using spring-boot-1.5.19

**pom.xml**

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**Main file**

```
        @SpringBootApplication
public class AwsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AwsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSqs);
    }

    @Bean
    public NotificationMessagingTemplate notificationMessagingTemplate(
            AmazonSNS amazonSNS) {
        return new NotificationMessagingTemplate(amazonSNS);
    }

    @Bean
    public IotClient getIotClient() {
        return IotClient.builder()
                .credentialsProvider(() -> AwsBasicCredentials.create(AWS_ACCESSKEY, AWS_SECRETKEY))
                .credentialsProvider(() -> InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.create().resolveCredentials())
                .region(Region.US_EAST_2)
                .build();
    }
   }
```

**SQS listener class**

```
@SqsListener(value = "${sqs.consumer.name}")
public void receiveSnsSqs(String message, @NotificationMessage Employee employee) {
    System.out.println("SNS Consumer received the message::"+message);
    System.out.println("SNS Consumer received the notificationMessage::"+employee);
    }
```

In the above listener class, I am able to receive the message but the employee is getting as null. I am sending a message from AWS SNS directly.

As I mentioned it was working fine before it stopped working after migrating the spring version to 2.2.1 release.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `2.3.0.RELEASE` spring version and just face the same issue.
After I put `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` to the `QueueMessageHandlerFactory` the problem is solved.
here is my QueueMessageHandlerFactory bean.

```java
  @Bean
  public QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    messageConverter.setStrictContentTypeMatch(false);
    messageConverter.getObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());


    QueueMessageHandlerFactory factory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
    factory.setMessageConverters(Collections.singletonList(messageConverter));
    return factory;
  }
```